# Rabbits ate the blueberry shrubs I planted right down to the ground. Will the shrubs grow back?

Tags: pest-control, shrubs

I made the mistake of not setting up chicken wire and the rabbits ate these 24" bushes I just planted. All that remains are 1-2 little twigs, stripped of all the branches and leaves.

Will these plants grow back in spring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luke, I've done the same dang thing, this is the second year I've not protected my blue berries and I can pretty much assure you and myself, those blueberry shrubs will grow back if there is enough plant material left.  Unfortunately those dang bunnies ate the buds meant for berries.  You will not have any flowers or berries but the plants should survive so you (and mesef) can protect them for next year's harvest.

Be nice to see a picture of your shrubs. But, no matter what, you have to get them protected now. If those bunnies eat all of the cambium (beneath the bark) and all of the buds, even  vegetative buds for leaves, you could lose the entire plant.  Please send  a picture.  Hey, I love bunnies.  It is fairly easy to protect your garden or green house from bunnies.  I've also got lots of cats from around the neighborhood so sad, but I won't be having a population problem from bunnies.

Chicken wire, cheap and it works if you get the edges at the soil level pinned down.  Row cloth works as well.  Just make sure the bunnies can't dig under.  Bunnies don't dig under something overnight usually.  I am using both, chicken wire to keep bunnies away from the shrubs and row cloth in case one gets in...the row cloth also protects the few buds that might no have been eaten.  Water them well when you have a few warm days.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will take a picture soon. I just got four more blueberry plants (two different varieties) and put them in the ground, now that it's getting up to 50 each day. I have them protected with a temporary fence that I wrapped on steel T-posts and pinned down at the base. Crossing my fingers...

Answer (score 4):

Rabbits will eat any part of the blue berry bush that they can reach. As noted by Stormy,  ; chicken wire better fencing is needed. I did find that human hair ( barber or beauty shop) sprinkled around does give additional discouragement.